# Receiving Related Entities from Oracle DB via EF6 and LINQ

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework, linq

I am working on a Web-Application that can display data from an Oracle database.

For Example if I need to display a Part, I need following Relations:

```
Parts have 0-1 AdditionalInformations
Parts have 0-1 ReferencePart
Parts have 1   Type 
Parts have 1-* Tasks
Parts have 0-* Locations
```

furthermore:

```
AdditionalInformations have 0-* Users
And Locations          have 1   AdditionalLocationInfo
```

So I want to get a Part from db, dispose the context and after that I want to display the Part including the previously mentioned relations.

I am using EntityFramework 6 with LINQ for the queries. And an ORACLE 12c DATABASE to hold the Data

```
var query = from part in _dbcontext.Part.AsNoTracking()
            where part.Id == partId
            select part;
return query
        .Include(p => p.Type)
        .Include(p => p.AdditionalInformations.Users)
        .Include(p => p.ReferencePart)
        .Include(p => p.Locations.Select(l => l.AdditionalLocationInfo))
        .Include(p => p.Tasks)
        .SingleOrDefault();
```

Sadly this gives me ORA-01790 exception...

If I use less Includes it works! :

```
var query = from part in _dbcontext.Part.AsNoTracking()
            where part.Id == partId
            select part;
return query
        .Include(p => p.Type)
        .Include(p => p.Locations.Select(l => l.AdditionalLocationInfo))
        .SingleOrDefault();


var query = from part in _dbcontext.Part.AsNoTracking()
            where part.Id == partId
            select part;
return query
        .Include(p => p.Type)
        .Include(p => p.AdditionalInformations.Users)
        .Include(p => p.ReferencePart)
        .SingleOrDefault();
```

But Yeah, I need all Relations...

So please give me Input on how to solve this problem:) Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like the exception occurred because EF generated SQL statement which Oracle DB doesn't support or unable to handle it. Please check generated SQL statement in debug mode.

Comment: I can't because the Program crashes right when I do the Includes... I have read somewhere that Oracle is not able to handle many Includes.